# % in subsection

Tags: symbols

I have searched the web but did not find anything besides the command `\texorpdfstring` for including math symbols which did btw not work for me

I simply want to add a percent symbol in my subsection i.e.

```
\subsection{under 5%}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Since `%` means the comment character in (La)TeX it must be escaped, i.e. use `\%`: `\subsection{Under 5\%}` or with `siunitx` package: `\subsection{Under \SI{5}{\percent}}` for a better display

Answer (score 3):

The `%` means the comment character in (La)TeX usually (unless catcodes are changed, but let us assume this hasn't be done).

Now `\subsection{under 5%}` will fail of course, since the closing `}` bracket of the `\subsection` command isn't read any longer and `TeX` chokes on this.

As usual, a special character like `%` must be escaped with `\`, i.e. `\%` or  the special command `\textpercent` or `\SI{5}{\percent}`, the later form does not work with bookmark pdf strings, however, in this case, apply `\textorpdfstring{\SI{5}{\percent}}{\num{5}\textpercent}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{under 5\%}
\section{under \texorpdfstring{\SI{5}{\percent}}{\num{5}\textpercent}}
\end{document}
```

I omitted a screenshot

Comment: I would add that `5\%` and `\num{5}\textpercent` set the per cent sign up close, while `\SI{5}{\percent}` inserts a thinspace between number and unit. The latter is correct according to Oxford Style, but other style guides prefer to set per cent signs up close to the number. If you want to replicate the version with thinspace for the former two varieties, you have to use `5\,\%` or `\num{5}\,\textpercent`, respectively.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: I will add you suggestions later on, thanks!